# Jenkinfile ssh issue with sed command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I have written one Jenkinsfile and in one step I am stuck, that is basically deploy stage. In deploy stage there is a step where I have to ssh into one server and run couple of commands. Earlier it was working fine, but when i add sed command with some regex then Jenkins is showing syntax error. Below is the snippet.

```
                steps {
                      sshagent ( credentials: []) {

sh '''
echo "Tag=miqp-server_${BUILD_NUMBER}" > sshenv
echo "target=${DeployTo}" >> sshenv
scp sshenv root@SERVERIP:~/.ssh/environment
ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root SERVERIP <<'EOF'

#DEPLOYMENT_NAME="miqp-server-dep"
#CONTAINER_NAME="miqp-server-dev"
#NEW_DOCKER_IMAGE="2xxxxxxxxxx6.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/miqp-devops:${Tag}"
RELEASE_NAME=miqp-server-dep

if [ "${target}" = "None" ]
then
  echo "No deployment to K8s"
else

cd /root/kubernetes-ingress/dev/miqp-server-dep/
sed -i "s/^\([[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*\).*/\1$Tag/" values.yaml
helm upgrade -f values.yaml $RELEASE_NAME miqp-server-dep.0.1.0.tgz

#kubectl set image deployment/$DEPLOYMENT_NAME $CONTAINER_NAME=$NEW_DOCKER_IMAGE -n devops-dev
#kubectl rollout status deployment $DEPLOYMENT_NAME -n devops-dev

fi
EOF'''
```

And the error Jenkins throwing is

```
WorkflowScript: 156: unexpected char: '\' @ line 156, column 13.
   sed -i "s/^\([[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*\).*/\1$Tag/" values.yaml
               ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have solved the issue by giving escape character

```
sed -i "s/^\([[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*\).*/\1$Tag/" values.yaml 

sed -i "s/^\\([[:space:]]*tag:[[:space:]]*\\).*/\\1$Tag/" values.yaml
```

Thanks